# how kotlin serialize JSONObject or Map to string with sorted keys?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to serialize  a JSONObject or  a Map to string with sorted_keys.

```kotlin
val mapObject = mapOf<String, Any>(
    "b" to arrayOf(
        "bb",
        mapOf<String, Any>(
            "bbb" to "bbb",
            "aaa" to "aaa"
        ), 
        "aa"
    ),
    "a" to "a"
)
val jsonObject = JSONObject(mapObject)
println(jsonObject.toString())
```

It prints

```
{"b":["bb",{"bbb":"bbb","aaa":"aaa"},"aa"],"a":"a"}
```

but I want it prints

```
{"a": "a", "b": ["bb", {"aaa": "aaa", "bbb": "bbb"}, "aa"]}
```

In Python there is

```py
json.dumps(jsonObject, sort_keys=True)
```

to do this.

In Swift there is

```
jsonObject.rawString(options: [.sortedKeys])
```

to do this

but there seems to be no elegant method to do this in Android Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONObject` is primarily an unsafe & intermediary format, so there aren't a ton of options for working with it in that form, primarily favoring deserialization to "actual" class representations for any work.

To this end, if you have control over the input of your map, you could switch from using `mapOf<String, Any>` to `sortedMapOf<String, Any>` - Kotlin maintains distinct implementations for this (similarly, if you wanted to edit your map after construction, you'd want a `mutableMapOf<String, Any>`).

If you already have an existing map, you can also use the method `toSortedMap`.

By default, all ordering should be done based on the natural order of the keys.